# Combine Azure ad b2c and Azure MFA

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to combine Azure ad b2c and Azure MFA so users can use push notifications and TOTP codes in the MS authenticator app? If so how?

Comment: How would Azure DevOps help?

Comment: Oh sorry, wrong copy/past link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-mfa

Comment: Ah, I see. That describes the OOTB integration which allows SMS and phone call only AFAICT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD B2C supports MFA out of the box using voice calls and SMS.

Authenticator or TOTP is not currently supported but in the backlog.

Answer (score 1):

Apart of enabling MFA that uses SMS and voice calls which is [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-multi-factor-authentication) and doesn't require any additional development, you can integrate **TOTP-based Multi-Factor Authentication** with Azure AD B2C.

This involves an additional development:

1. *Custom policy* to support TOTP flow.
2. Simple *web-client* (for presenting a page with QR code and reading user's input).
3. Two *custom REST API endpoints* (for generating secret key, QR code and validating TOTP code).

Sign-in flow with TOTP MFA:
[image: AD B2C TOTP MFA flow]

For more details, please refer to Microsoft [Azure AD B2C: TOTP multi-factor authentication](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-mfa-totp) sample implementation Github project.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try AD B2C, but technically it seems possible refer to the links.
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-authentication-methods#microsoft-authenticator-app

If you properly setup Azure AD B2C, you can add new account in Microsoft Authenticator App > Add account > (your AD url and code).

I’ve used AD with MS Authenticator App in my company and it worked well. So, Azure AD B2C could provide it also.